# Concatenated enum return type

Tags: ios, swift, struct, enums

I have an enum that looks like this:

```
class CustomButton {
  struct Section {
    enum Root: Int {
      case rootFirst, rootSecond, rootThird
    }

    enum Top: Int {
      case topFirst, topSecond, topThird
    }
  }

  var type: Any?
}
```

I have different `CustomButton` that are from different `Section` and I want to be able to detect of which type is every `CustomButton` by doing something like `customButton.type`.

Right now I am able to do it by creating a `type` variable on the `CustomButton` class but with `Any` as var type because it should store different button types. The problem is that every time I get the `type` variable, I have to check which type of button I am working with, with something like `type(of: type)` and then, cast that `Any` type to what `type(of: buttonType)` is reporting so that I can access `topFirst` or `rootSecond` depending on the type.

Is there an easier way of doing that? I bet there is but I have found nothing after some hours of research and I am also quite new to Swift.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `CustomButton` is supposed to be a subclass of `UIButton`? What different values could `type` take? Is it supposed to be other `UIButton` subclasses or just different values of `Section`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, `CustomButton` is a subclass of `UIButton`. `type` should take all different values from all enums like `Root.rootFirst` and `Top.topSecond`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your structure is overcomplicated, and perhaps I have misunderstood it, but I *think* what you want to do is this:

```
class CustomButton {

    enum Section { // Not a `struct`, but an `enum`
        enum Root: Int {
            case rootFirst, rootSecond, rootThird
        }

        enum Top: Int {
            case topFirst, topSecond, topThird
        }
        case root(Root), top(Top)
    }

    var type: Section?
}

var cb = CustomButton()
cb.type = CustomButton.Section.root(.rootFirst)
cb.type = CustomButton.Section.top(.topSecond)
```

Your `Section` struct is really not a struct at all as it has no members - it's simply a scope. As soon as one thinks about what value it could contain, it becomes clear that nested enum is really the answer.

Comment: I was about to post my answer using recursive enums, because I completely forgot about the fact that enums can have enums defined inside them, so your solution is even better, upvoted.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Why don't you post your answer, anyway? Both approaches are non-trivial and thus instructive...

Comment: fair enough, posted it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it really is what I was looking for and it has simplified a lot the structure ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the only point of defining the `Section` struct was to wrap the two enums inside it, I would recommend defining `Section` as a recursive enum instead.

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    indirect enum Section {
        case number(Int)
        case Root(Section)
        case Top(Section)
    }

    var type: Section?
}

let rootFirstButton = CustomButton()
let rootFirstType = CustomButton.Section.Root(.number(1))
rootFirstButton.type = rootFirstType

let topSecondButton = CustomButton()
topSecondButton.type = CustomButton.Section.Top(.number(2))
```

Bear in mind that for this specific issue, I would probably use @Grimxn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46216760/4667835), since there's no real need for the enum to be recursive, you only want `Root` and `Top` to be able to take values of the case `number` while using the recursive approach, even a value of `CustomButton.Section.Root(.Top(.number(3)))`. So unless you plan on embedding sections in sections, you don't need the recursive `enum`.

Comment: Upvoted for the effort but Grimxn approach is perfect, nice and clean!